# `join` with -e "NA" parameter incorrectly fills "NA" into a non-empty field

Tags: shell, join

I am encountering a weird issue with `join` in a script I've written.

I have two files, say:

File1.txt (1st field: cluster size; 2nd field: brain coordinates)

```
54285;-40,-64,-2
5446;-32,6,24
```

File2.txt (1st field: cluster index; 2nd field: z-value; 3rd field: brain coordinates)

```
2;7.59;-40,-64,-2
2;7.33;62,-60,14
1;5.78;-32,6,24
1;5.66;-50,16,34
```

Where I am joining on the last field, the brain coordinates.

When I use the command

```
join -a 2 -e "NA" -1 2 -2 3 -t ";" -o "2.1 1.1 2.2 0" File1.txt File2.txt
```

I expect

```
2;54285;7.59;-40,-64,-2
2;NA;7.33;62,-60,14
1;5446;5.78;-32,6,24
1;NA;5.66;-50,16,34
```

But I get

```
2;54285;7.59;-40,-64,-2
2;NA;7.33;62,-60,14
1;NA;5.78;-32,6,24
1;NA;5.66;-50,16,34
```

Such that the cluster size is missing on row 3 (i.e., cluster size for cluster #1, "5446").

If I edit File2 to take out lines that don't have a match in File1, i.e.:

File2.txt

```
2;7.59;-40,-64,-2
1;5.78;-32,6,24
```

I get the expected output:

```
2;54285;7.59;-40,-64,-2
1;5446;5.78;-32,6,24
```

If I edit File2.txt like so, adding a line without a cluster-size value to cluster #1:

File2.txt

```
2;7.59;-40,-64,-2
1;5.78;-32,6,24
1;5.66;-50,16,34
```

I also get the expected output:

```
2;54285;7.59;-40,-64,-2
1;5446;5.78;-32,6,24
1;NA;5.66;-50,16,34
```

BUT, if I edit File2.txt like so, adding a line without a cluster-size value to cluster #2:

File2.txt

```
2;7.59;-40,-64,-2
2;7.33;62,-60,14
1;5.78;-32,6,24
```

Then I do not receive the expected output:

```
2;54285;7.59;-40,-64,-2
2;NA;7.33;62,-60,14
1;NA;5.78;-32,6,24
```

Can anyone give me any insight into why this is occurring? Have I done something wrong, or is there something quirky going on with `join` that I haven't been able to suss out from the man page?

Although alternative solutions to joining these files (that is, using different tools than `join`) , I am most interested in figuring out *why* the current command isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input files to the [join command must be sorted on join fields](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html)

Try this instead (note that this uses process substitution, which is a bashism)

```
join -a 2 -e "NA" -1 2 -2 3 -t ";" -o "2.1 1.1 2.2 0" <(sort -k2,2 -t';' File1.txt)\
 <(sort -k3,3 -t';' File2.txt)
1;5446;5.78;-32,6,24
2;54285;7.59;-40,-64,-2
1;NA;5.66;-50,16,34
2;NA;7.33;62,-60,14
```

Comment: I appreciate this. I had misunderstood the man page and thought that my files were already sorted correctly.